# Yii update query not working as expected

Tags: php, yii

This is my code

```
        $tablename = 'engine4_messages_recipients';
        $columns = array('inbox_read'=>1);
        $whereCondition = 'user_id=:user_id AND conversation_id=:conversation_id AND inbox_message_id!=NULL';
        $whereConditionParams = array(':user_id'=>$user_id,':conversation_id'=>$conversation_id);
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->update($tablename,$columns,$whereCondition,$whereConditionParams);
```

DB table ::

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `engine4_messages_recipients` (
`user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`conversation_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`inbox_message_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`inbox_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`inbox_read` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`inbox_deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`outbox_message_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`outbox_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`outbox_deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`conversation_id`),
 KEY `INBOX_UPDATED` (`user_id`,`conversation_id`,`inbox_updated`),
 KEY `OUTBOX_UPDATED` (`user_id`,`conversation_id`,`outbox_updated`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `engine4_messages_recipients`

INSERT INTO `engine4_messages_recipients` (`user_id`, `conversation_id`, `inbox_message_id`, `inbox_updated`, `inbox_read`, `inbox_deleted`, `outbox_message_id`, `outbox_updated`, `outbox_deleted`) VALUES
(2, 1, 8, '2014-09-18 12:24:16', 0, 0, 7, '2014-09-11 10:49:40', 1),
(3, 1, 7, '2014-09-11 10:49:40', 0, 0, 8, '2014-09-18 12:24:16', 0);

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: This looks about right. What is the expected and observed behaviour?

Comment: Did you get an exception? Please set YII_DEBUG to true, and show us the exception. Why don't you work with models for this query? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar

Comment: you use `createCommand` so you can create own sql (string\query) and execute it

Comment: I did't get any exception. How do i set YII_DEBUG to true. I am a beginner level programmer

Comment: It is already YII_DEBUG is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$tablename = 'engine4_messages_recipients';

$columns = array('inbox_read'=>1);

$whereCondition = 'user_id=:user_id AND conversation_id=:conversation_id AND inbox_message_id!=:inbox_message_id';

$whereConditionParams = array(':user_id'=>$user_id,':conversation_id'=>$conversation_id,':inbox_message_id'=>NULL);

$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->update($tablename,$columns,$whereCondition,$whereConditionParams);
```

Comment: Post your database sql dumps queries so i will check at my end.

Comment: Can you let me know what was the issue?

Comment: Use ' inbox_message_id IS NOT NULL' instead of using   'inbox_message_id!=NULL'

Please edit your answer